Google gms Connections not possible in android studio
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.2:.
Required by:
project :


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Please solve this and help me

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
